# How to add a tooltip to Folium ColorLine for further data information?

Tags: python, data-visualization, folium

I would like to draw a colored GPS Track on a folium map. The color should be based on the current speed.
For this purpose, I use the Folium ColorLine.
On hovering over the colored line section with the mouse, I want further information as a tooltip or info-box about that particular line section, like the speed (and other information I got like acceleration, yaw_rate, ect.)
However I do not manage to get this to work. The tooltip argument does nothing.
Below is a small example with sample values.
Any suggestions on how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

```py
import folium 
import branca.colormap

speed = [50, 51, 52, 56, 55, 54, 53]
longitudes = [10.415180, 10.415179, 10.415180, 10.415187, 10.415201, 10.415224, 10.415251, 10.415282]
latitudes = [51.919775, 51.919765, 51.919759, 51.919749, 51.919727, 51.919694, 51.919654, 51.919607]
route = [(lat, lon) for lat, lon in zip(latitudes, longitudes)]

colormap = branca.colormap.linear.YlOrRd_09.scale(50,56).to_step(6)

map_route = folium.Map(location=[route[0][0], route[0][1]], zoom_start=20)
folium.ColorLine(positions=route, colormap=colormap, weight=10, colors=speed, tooltip=[str(i) for i in speed]).add_to(map_route)

map_route
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any example where the `forlium.ColorLine()` tooltip is valid. I added the tooltip by adding a colormap and a marker, using `itertools.zip_longest()` since the list lengths of the two lists are different.

```
import folium 
import branca.colormap
from itertools import zip_longest
import numpy as np

speed = [50, 51, 52, 56, 55, 54, 53]
longitudes = [10.415180, 10.415179, 10.415180, 10.415187, 10.415201, 10.415224, 10.415251, 10.415282]
latitudes = [51.919775, 51.919765, 51.919759, 51.919749, 51.919727, 51.919694, 51.919654, 51.919607]
route = [[lat, lon] for lat, lon in zip(latitudes, longitudes)]
tooltip = [str(i) for i in speed]
colormap = branca.colormap.linear.YlOrRd_09.scale(50,56).to_step(6)

map_route = folium.Map(location=[route[0][0], route[0][1]], zoom_start=20)
folium.ColorLine(positions=route, colormap=colormap, weight=10, colors=speed).add_to(map_route)
for i,p in zip_longest(speed,route, fillvalue=np.mean(speed)):
    # print(i,p)
    folium.Marker(p, tooltip=i).add_to(map_route)

map_route.add_child(colormap)
map_route
```

[image]